# Handling redux state with filtering, sorting and pagination done in backend

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The user has access to a list of items and has the ability to search, sort and change pages. The API returns paginated, sorted and filtered items. When some parameters are changed, how should the new data merge with the current state? Just merging them together won't work because not all items should be shown when the user inputs a search query, for example.

My ideas:

- Wiping everything and storing the new data. Seems inefficient because the same items will be loaded multiple times.
- Having a separate reducer. This approach produces duplicates and makes the app more complex.

Comment: This is very generic question and many parameters may affect the solution. For example, do you have all data up front, or only one page at a time? Can your API return only "changed" values? And so on. Also, can you elaborate how separate reducer may solve the problem?

Comment: The data is loaded page by page (that's more efficient for large collections of items). The API can't return only changed values. I've had an idea of keeping all the items and the items currently displayed (that suit the parameters) in separate structures. But now I'm thinking of keeping all the items in one structure and only the id's for the current items in the other. That approach would not yield duplicates.

Comment: I think this is a way to go. I think separate structure would not give you efficiency, but complicate things. Easier to wipe and load. You can look at solutions like react-query and swr to reduce amount of data passed back and forth. I haven't used them myself, so I can be mistaken about it, but still worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is storing each query, page is just another query argument:

```
{
  //the key is the query sent to the api
  //  this could be an url query string or
  //  the query object to json
  'page=1&sort-by=first&desc' : {
    //status of the request (explains itself)
    requested:true,
    loading:false,
    error:false,
    result:[2,1]//ids in this page
  },
  //here are all the data items with their own status
  data: {
    "1":{
      //request status (you may want to get)
      //  just one item by id
      requested:true,
      loading:false,
      error:false,
      //the actual entity
      result: {
        id: 1,
        first:'z'
      }
    },
    "2":{
      //loading, requested ...
      result: {
        id:2,
        first:"a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you do crud then you should wipe out all the data from state because you are doing sorting and/or filtering on the server so any update could change any page set. You can add a status `stale` and `refreshing` so a component can show stale data but refresh it in the background. Normally you'd do caching in the service worker but since redux needs the status of your request you could add the extra effort and implement it in the (thunk) actions and selectors.